# v7 Tintmanager error when using an external library for android?

Tags: android, git, stack, dependencies, runtime

I am trying to use this tagview from this git repo https://github.com/Cutta/TagView as shown below

```
 <com.cunoraz.tagview.TagView
        android:background="#E4E4E4"
        android:id="@+id/codes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Type in Your Text Here"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view" />
```

However, I am getting this error ?

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.widget.TintManager
```

Here is the full stack trace

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.widget.TintManager
                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.<init>(TabLayout.java:1185)
                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:656)
                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTabView(TabLayout.java:695)
                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:386)
                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:361)
                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:645)
                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(TabLayout.java:616)
                                                                   at com.athena.athena.MainActivitys.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:73)
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Lastly, here are my gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:LikeButton:0.1.7'
compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.github.Cutta:TagView:c15dd8288a'

compile 'com.kymjs.rxvolley:rxvolley:1.0.1'
compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
compile 'com.kymjs.rxvolley:rxvolley:1.0.1'
compile 'com.github.alamkanak:android-week-view:1.2.6'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'org.lucasr.dspec:dspec:0.1.1'
compile 'com.github.Cutta:TagView:c15dd8288a'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.yqritc:recyclerview-flexibledivider:1.2.6'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
compile 'com.yalantis:phoenix:1.2.3'
compile 'me.tatarka.support:jobscheduler:0.1.1'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.github.curioustechizen.android-ago:library:1.3.0'
compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.1'
compile 'com.yalantis:sidemenu:1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
compile 'co.dift.ui.swipetoaction:library:1.1'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.1'
compile 'com.vstechlab.easyfonts:easyfonts:1.0.0'
 }
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?